Get this error statement: Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Whenever I try to run an app, I get the error code below. There is absolutely no solution for this online, and it is getting really frustrating.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1629
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`
I tried every article I could find in Google and followed other peoples solutions for solving similar problems but none of the solutions solved the problem. `

How are people supposed to reproduce this to help you?

Sorry, I am new to this. What do you mean?

Any help you could give would be much appreciated. I am trying to work my through the Udemy complete Flutter course, and I'm stuck until I fix this issue. I have tried every single online solution and none of them work.

Is there a way I can share my file so you can have a look?

run your Gradle command with the -d flag, to get debug ouput (warning: that will be a lot!). Search for the error message there.  Maybe something useful is there before the error.

Here is the verbose text from when I run the flutter.
https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ao00-W21cZdkkZBaTd7yXAAppHgdpA?e=mGvTNf
I would really appreciate your help with how to solve it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please don't link additional information from a comment. [edit] the question and add the relevant parts (do your best to find them) to the question directly.

The solution that worked for my system so try you

Delete pubspec.lock file
Then flutter pub get
Run the project

